# Mount image of unknown filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I have an image of a filesystem that I'm trying to mount. Unfortunately I have no idea what filesystem is in it. I'll show you what I have done so far.

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant# file some.img
some.img: x86 boot sector
```

So, ok there is some sort of image. Next I tried to look at it with `fdisk`

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant# fdisk -l some.img

Disk some.img: 1986 MB, 1986228224 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 241 cylinders, total 3879352 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

This doesn't look like a partition table
Probably you selected the wrong device.

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
some.img1               0   498925567   249462784    0  Empty
some.img2       830668801   830668859          29+   0  Empty
some.img3           90433  3430048064  1714978816    0  Empty
some.img4   ?           0           0           0    0  Empty
```

But here I get stuck. The System is `Empty`, whatever that means.

I tried to mount it as `ext2`, `ext3`, `ext4` or `vfat` for the largest partition (some.img3), calculating an offset like so:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant# mount -o ro,loop,offset=46301696 -t  ext3 some.img /mnt/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Using `kpartx` I tried to have a closer look, but I am not very well versed with `kpartx`. Here is the output:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant# kpartx some.img
loop0p1 : 0 498925568 /dev/loop0 0
loop0p2 : 0 59 /dev/loop0 830668801
loop0p3 : 0 3429957632 /dev/loop0 90433
loop deleted : /dev/loop0
```

To mee this looks like it doesn't even want to create the loop device? This is where I am stuck... again: I am trying to mount the large block that you can see in `fdisk`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!